# Bootstrap tooltip title attribute not working with angular 6

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have configured bootstrap tooltip in angular template like

```
<img src="/img"
    *ngIf="tooltip.isTrue"
    [title]="{{toolTip.content}}"
    class="mb-3 ml-1"
    [attr.data-trigger]="'hover'"
    [attr.data-toggle]="'tooltip'"
    [attr.data-placement]="'right'"/>
```

title content is dynamic.This still shows title in default HTML style not as bootstrap, and bootstrap tooltip comes up as "undefined" on hover.

i have tried

```
title={{tooltip.content}}
[attr.data-title]="tooltip.content"
ngDataTitle={{tooltip.content}}
```

None worked.

Comment: you have a random ] in your  [title]="{{toolTip.content]}}"

Comment: @rleffler sorry it was typo error , Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out

```
[attr.data-original-title]="toolTip.content"
```

Thanks :)